# How to get the language selectbox and login text on the same line?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code like this for displaying menu, login, register and select language on the same line. How do I get the Language selectbox on the same line?

The missing code is implemented here.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0TY5.png)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        @*<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">xxxxx</a>*@
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/WebZenter" tabindex="-1">
            <span style="padding-left: 30px">xxxxxx</span>
            <img alt="Brand" src="~/CustomerFiles/BeoTjenester/WebZenter50x50.png" width="20" height="20" style="margin-top: -20px;" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="xxxxxxxx" asp-action="Jobs">xxxxxh</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">DinnerOut<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="DinnerOut" asp-action="Index">Create Bill</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="DinnerOut" asp-action="Select">Select Bill</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
        {
            <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">@Localizer["Hello"] @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Log off</button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        }
        else
        {
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> @Localizer["Register"]</a></li>
                <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> @Localizer["Login"]</a></li>
                <li>
                    <div title="@Localizer["Request culture provider:"] @requestCulture?.Provider?.GetType().Name" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="ChangeLanguage"
                              asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path"
                              method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                            @Localizer["Language"] <select name="culture"
                                                           onchange="this.form.submit();"
                                                           asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems"></select>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Missing code is added.

Comment: Where is the code that adds the "Register" and "Log in" links? That's not included here, so it's basically impossible to tell you how to format the code so that it's on the same line as those.

Comment: Sorry - was to quick here.